# Sum of an AP Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

There is this proof for the sum of a GP series that is totally in what I call the **Summation Formula Realm**.  For this proof we operate upon the summation formula only, instead of operating upon the expanded series like:
a + ar + ar<sup>2</sup> + ar<sup>3</sup> + ........ + ar<sup>n-1</sup>

The following figure shows the proof:

[image]

---

Is there a similar proof for the sum of an AP series?  I don't want the proof which utilizes the expanded series:
a + (a+d) + (a+2d) + ..... + (a+{n-1}*d)
since I already know that

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a+kd) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} kd = a \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1 + d \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = a\cdot n+d\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}2,
$$
where the last equality uses a fundamental formula for the sum of the first several integers. So the question really boils down to how to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n-1)}2$, which has many proofs (using induction, for example) and should be easy to find.